# Django ORM between MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: django, orm

I'm learning some django lecture that used postgresql database.

But I am familiar with MySQL so I want to use mysql.

I heard that Django ORM automatically convert command to query.(So user do not have to know exact database query)

I want to know that, Can I use mysql instead of postgresql in this lecture?

Any problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's ORM by default supports

- PostgreSQL
- MySQL
- SQLite
- Oracle

with the right bindings.

[You would require `psycopg2` in order for the postgres](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes) connections to work. Once the setup is complete, the ORM can convert from model based queries to raw sql. You can inspect that using the `.query` on the queryset.
Note that this also implies the ORM can support some of the advanced features of postgresql